# How do I map a dictionary onto a dataframe column without including the header?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to apply to a DataFrame column to create a new column. I made the dictionary from another DataFrame that has columns named 'ID' and 'SMILES', like this:

```
dictionary = smiles_df.set_index('ID').T.to_dict()
```

The dictionary looks like this:

```
 'N[C@@H](Cc1c[nH]c2ccccc12)C(=O)NO': {'SMILES': '[NH3+]C(Cc1c[nH]c2ccccc12)C(O)=NO'},
 'Clc1ccc(Nc2nnc(Cc3ccncc3)c3ccccc23)cc1': {'SMILES': 'Clc1ccc(Nc2nnc(Cc3ccncc3)c3ccccc23)cc1'},
 'Oc1ccc(cc1)-c1nc(c([nH]1)-c1ccc(F)cc1)-c1ccncc1': {'SMILES': '[O-]c1ccc(-c2nc(-c3ccncc3)c(-c3ccc(F)cc3)[n-]2)cc1'},
```

I apply the dictionary like this:

```
df['processed_SMILES'] = df['SMILES'].map(dictionary)
```

The output in the `df['processed_SMILES']` looks like this:

```
{'SMILES': 'CC(=O)CCCCn1c(=O)c2c(ncn2C)n(C)c1=O'}
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
'CC(=O)CCCCn1c(=O)c2c(ncn2C)n(C)c1=O'
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Just remove that from your dictionary, `dictionary = {k:v['SMILES'] for k,v in dictionary.items()}`. It's not a "header", btw. It's that your dictionary has *other dictionaries* as a value

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the dictionary comes from dataframe, so we could use a Series instead the DataFrame to generate the dict:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead:

```
dictionary = smiles_df.set_index('ID')['SMILES'].to_dict()
```

Or:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(smiles_df['ID'], smiles_df['SMILES']))
```